# AWS Autoscaling Pricing Model

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

I have a reserved instance and i am creating an auto scaling group. The rule is also created for when the new instance should be scaled up and down. I need to know how that new scaled instance would be billed as it should be billed as "Pay as you use" model and not reserved pricing. Please advise how the pricing works in this scenarios

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Your question is not programming related and therefore shouldn't be asked on stackoverflow. Maybe you would be better at, [contacting amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/)

Answer (score 0):

The pricing is exactly as if you had manually started an instance of the same type and left it running for the same time (assuming that this is a regular autoscaling group and not the kind that uses spot instances).

If you have purchased a reserved instance then it may be used for an instance started by autoscaling. It shouldn't make any difference to your overall bill which way round the RI is used